# Maximum Expected Long Term Utility.

Tags: game-theory, information-theory, entropy, mutual-information

I have the following question in Dynamic Games where the first player completely knows the state over all the period $T$ and tries to send signals to the second player (second player only knows the state of the previous stage) so that they match their actions to obtain the maximum long term utility.

Consider the following game with two players, $A_i$ is the action set of the player $i$. The set of nature states is denoted by $A_0$. The nature is Identically Independently Distributed. All the sets are discrete and finite. The strategies of the long term game are defined as follows:

$$A_{1,t} = \sigma_{1,t}(A_0^T, A_1^{t-1}, A_2^{t-1})$$
$$A_{2,t} = \sigma_{2,t}(A_0^{t-1}, A_1^{t-1}, A_2^{t-1})$$

Where $A_j^t$ stands for the classical notation for a sequence of random variables $A_{j,1}, .......... , A_{j,t}$.

Now the Questions is:

By assuming $A_0 = A_1 = A_2 = \{a , b\}$ and the following team game utility:
$$u(a_0, a_1, a_2) = \begin{cases} 1 & \text{if} \;  a_0 = a_1 = a_2 \\ 0 & \text{otherwise} \end{cases}$$

Prove that the maximum expected long-term utility is about $0.81$

---

The way I have attempted to answer this question:

First there is this corollary: any implementable joint distribution $Q(a_0,a_1,a_2)$
has to necessarily verify the following entropy condition:
$$ H_Q(A_0,A_1,A_2) \geq H_Q(A_0) + H_Q(A_2) $$

In addition to that, the long term utility is: $\frac{1}{T} \sum_{t = 1}^{T} U(a(t)) = q_1u_1 + q_2u_2$

where $u_1$ contains the action profiles that yields a utility one and $u_2$ action profiles which yields zero and $q_1$ is the distribution of the action profiles that has utility one so we will have:

$\frac{1}{T} \sum_{t = 1}^{T} U(a(t)) = \mathbb{E}[u(a)] = q_1u_1 + q_2u_2 = q_1$

in addition to that what I only know but can't reach is: $\dfrac{h(q_1) - 1}{q_1 - 1} = \log_23$ the solution of this equation gives the answer which will be $0.81$ and $h(q_1)$ is the entropy: $h(q_1) = -q_1\log q_1 - (1-q_1)\log(1-q_1)$.

Comment: I'm struggling to understand the question. My understanding is: it's a two player, T period dynamic game. Both players simultaneously choose an action each turn, from the same action set ${a,b}$. They get a payoff of one if their actions both match the nature state. The nature states are either $a$ or $b$ randomly decided before the game starts. One player knows all the nature states, from the start. The other player only knows the nature state of the previous round. They jointly try to maximise the payoff function, and have the same payoff function. Is this all correct?

Comment: Does the second player remember nature states from more than one round ago? what is $a(t)$? Do you know what the maximising strategy is supposed to be, or do we also need to find a maxmising strategy?

Comment: @ZoeAllen You perfectly understand the question, so $a(t)$ is basically the action profile of (state, player one, player two) at stage $t$ player one knows the state from stage 1 to stage T while player two only knows the state from stage 1 to stage (t-1), I want to find the maximum utility only not the strategy that yields the maximum utility.